# How do I change the indenting for Excel's XML Data Export?

Tags: xml, excel

I am using Excel 2003's XML Data Source and exporting the data using the menu option Data -> XML -> Export.  The data exports fine, but the resulting elements are indenting using tabs.  This may sound trivial, but is there a way I can set the formatting of the indents to spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anyway to modify the indent character (or XML-writer formatting) of Excel's XmlMap export logic.  If you can, consider writing a simple macro to perform the export yourself to a string variable via the XmlMap object's ExportXml method, then perform a simple Replace of vbTab with Space(2) or whatever in the resulting string before writing it yourself to a file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can always run it through [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) afterwards.